# Modal rendering before object loads

Tags: html, angular

The `this.obj` data is populated after modal window load. So, how can I sync both data and modal?

Acomponent.ts

`this.dialog.showModal(this.referenceNumber);`

dialogComponent.ts

```
export class   DialogComponent {
   obj:any;
  showModal(name:String) {
  if(name!==null) {
      this.obj=name;
      $("#myModal").modal('show');
         }
  }
    hideModal():void {
    document.getElementById('close-modal').click();
  }
  errorModal() {
    $("#errorModal").modal('show');
  }
}
```

dialog.html

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Record saved Successfully{{obj}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach is not correct. If you want to do DOM manipulation using JQuery, you probably don't need Angular. Use your html as the template and control the DOM from within your component.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular approach is to control visibility of the modal via the javascript.

So something like:

```
<div *ngIf="showModal" id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="showModal=false">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Record saved Successfully{{obj}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the `*ngIf="showModal"` and (click) event handler on the button.

Your .ts file would need a `showModal: boolean;` property, and the button click handler would need run change detection if you are using push change detection.

Edit:
And yes, don't use jQuery in Angular. I recommend the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) library.